# How to set recaptcha key settings at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, recaptcha

I'm implementing the [recaptcha](http://www.google.com/recaptcha) control from google.

I built a simple c# test project from their example and all works.  Now, instead of having the PublicKey and PrivateKey in the aspx page, I'd rather assign these values at run time as they will most likely be pulled from either the web.config or a database table.

I tried the following in the Page_Load

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        recaptcha.PublicKey = "<deleted for obvious reasons>";
        recaptcha.PrivateKey = "<ditto>";
    }
```

but I get an error stating "reCAPTCHA needs to be configured with a public & private key."

I also tried overriding the oninit method of the page and assigning the values there, but no joy.

Any ideas on where this needs to go?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try using the value of `setincodebehind` in your tag, like this:

```
<recaptcha:RecaptchaControl ID="myRecaptcha" runat="server" 
  PublicKey="setincodebehind" PrivateKey="setincodebehind" ... />
```

That should let you set the keys in the codebehind properly.  There are a couple of other ways to do it as well.  For example, you can get the values from a static class like this:

```
<recaptcha:RecaptchaControl ID="myRecaptcha" runat="server" 
  PublicKey="<%= RecaptchaSettings.PublicKey %>" 
  PrivateKey="<%= RecaptchaSettings.PrivateKey %>" ... />
```

Where `RecaptchaSettings` is a class you provide.  Or, you could put the keys into an `appSettings` section of your web.config, and access them like this:

```
<recaptcha:RecaptchaControl ID="myRecaptcha" runat="server" 
  PublicKey="<%$appSettings:RecaptchaPublicKey %>" 
  PrivateKey="<%$appSettings:RecaptchaPrivateKey %>" ... />
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Messing around, it seems the `setincodebehind` can be any string. Thanks, this worked well.

Comment: I bungled around this for a while - yes - you must have PublicKey and PrivateKey attributes within the control on your view - but they don't need the correct values.  If they are not there - when accessing via codebehind - you get object not set to an instance error.

Comment: Using the "setincodebehind" method worked best for me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Another way to set key values, use `<appSettings>` keys `RecaptchaPublicKey` and `RecaptchaPrivateKey`. These values will be used automatically unless it is overridden during control declaration ([mjd79's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3119360/how-to-set-recaptcha-key-settings-at-runtime/3119992#3119992), first way).

**Pro**: if you have multiple declaration, you only need to keep the keys in one place, DRY principle.

This behaviour can be seen through the source code, [RecaptchaControl.cs, line 135-...](http://code.google.com/p/recaptcha/source/browse/trunk/recaptcha-plugins/dotnet/library/RecaptchaControl.cs#135):

```
public RecaptchaControl()
{
    this.publicKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RecaptchaPublicKey"];
    this.privateKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RecaptchaPrivateKey"];
    ...
```